# I'm using discord.py and i want to make a command where the sender asks to search for a specific video in youtube and it opens that in a new tab

Tags: discord.py

I'm using discord.py and I want to make a command where the sender asks for a specific video in YouTube and it opens that in a new tab for them, but I don't know how. Does anybody know?

Comment: How are you supposed to open a new tab in someone else's computer? If bots could do that it'd be a complete violation of the ToS and any privacy policies.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

token = "" # Insert your token on the left side
prefix = "" # Insert your prefix on the left side
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix) # Define bot as a discord bot

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): # This part is when the bot is connected, it will print a message in the console
  print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")
  return

@bot.command(name="search",help="Search something on YouTube") # The “name” and “help” attributes are optional
async def search(ctx, *, query): # Defining a bot command
  encodedQuery = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query) # URL Encode your search query (using the plus symbol for spaces)
  html = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={encodedQuery}") # Request the HTML
  video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode()) # Find video IDs
  yt_url = f"https://youtube.com/watch?v={video_ids[0]}" # Use a the video ID and f-strings to build the YT URL
  await ctx.message.reply(f"Here you are:\n{yt_url}") # Sends it :)

bot.run(token)
```

Source:

- [Search for YouTube Using Python with 6 Lines of Code (Article)](https://codefather.tech/blog/youtube-search-python/)
- [How to encode URLs in Python (Article)](https://www.urlencoder.io/python/)
- [discord.ext.commands guide (Official)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)
- [discord.ext.commands — Keyword-only arguments (Offical)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)
- [f-strings (Article)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: This code only sends the YouTube URL to the text channel where the command was used.